# Deploying a C++ application in the cloud

Tags: java, c++, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am completely new to hosting applications in the cloud.

I have a product that consists of 2 separate applications which communicate with each other via HTTP. One is written in (native, unmanaged) C++ (server side), the other is written in Java and includes a web/GUI front end.

I have a server side application that is written in native, unmanaged C++, which communicates with a Java web/GUI front end.

I want to explore the possibility of hosting it in the cloud and I've been looking at, and experimenting with, Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk in the first instance but I'm struggling to see the wood for the trees.

1) Is it possible to run a native, unmanaged C++ application using Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk?

2) If so, how do I deploy it alongside the war file?

Comment: Wouldn't these questions be better addressed by consulting the AWS documentation?

Comment: I've spent hours and hours reading through the AWS documentation. Like I said, I'm struggling to see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

"The cloud" is just an alternative to host an application using external, scalable servers.

1. I think you could perfectly run an application in a Amazon EC2, maybe this question could help: [Installing a Test Application on Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350685/installing-a-test-application-on-amazon-ec2)
2. For Mac OSX in the cloud you could check [xcloud](http://xcloud.me/) or [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com)
3. The link above should help.