# Deploy C++ application on Amazon

Tags: c++, amazon-ec2

I have written a stand alone C++ application, how can I deploy and run it on amazon ec2?

Right now, i just create an instance of amazon ec2, and  I m stacked there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Could you please tell me why that downvote ????

Comment: Maybe this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350685/installing-a-test-application-on-amazon-ec2